# Need i make reindex when i create new index in T-SQL?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, indexing

I need to create new index for table in database which size is around 300 gb, but need i perform any additioanl action after i complete with it ? My database engine is microsoft sql server 2008 ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, a brand new index is ready to use.

Just to be clear: in sql server, when you build a new index, statistics are ready and index is built accordin to your fill factor.

Reindex means: rebuild the index. But you just built it...